# Mask link not working

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a layer linked to a layer mask.

[image]

If I select an part of my layer and move it, the layer mask does not move.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?
I'm using Photoshop CC 2015

Answer (score 1):

> select [a] part of my layer

That's the key point.

Selections are relative to the layer **or** the mask, **not** both. A selection (marching ants) will *always* either move a piece of the layer it encompasses or the piece of the layer mask it encompasses. It will **never** adjust both the mask *and* the layer.

By creating a selection, Photoshop assumes you are working on *ether* the mask or the layer, since you can't paint on both at the same time, you can make a selection on both at the same time either. This is just how Photoshop functions, and always has.

If you wish to move a portion of the image after its been masked, then **apply** the layer mask, or .... duplicate the layer, move whatever you want to move and then adjust the mask on the duplicate to show what you want it to show.

Comment: To augment what Scott said, the "lock" keeps the layer and the mask together until they are unlocked. If you unlock the link, then you can move the mask independent of the image or vice versa. This comes in handy when you are using a gradient mask that is part of an adjustment layer. By moving the mask you actually change where the adjustment is applied without recreating the mask. There are other applications where you may move the pixel layer and keep the mask fixed. I realize this does not solve your problem but you need to live with the capabilities of the tool.